# R: Assign values to a new column based on values of another column where a condition is satisfied

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new column in a data.frame where its value is equal to the value in another data.frame where a particular condition is satisfied between two columns in each data frame.

The R pseudo-code being something like this:

`DF1$Activity <- DF2$Activity where DF2$NAME == DF1$NAME`

In each data.frame values for `$NAME` are unique in the column.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example along with the expected output.

Comment: Okay, for this problem, you can do some sort of operation in R that will give the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without an example its quite hard to tell. But from your description it sounds like a `base::merge` or `dplyr::inner_join` operation. Those are quite fast in comparison to `if` statements.

Cheers

Comment: Both methods (`base::merge` and `dplyr::inner_join`) worked. Had a slight hiccup with incorrect column names, but those were resolved with `rename(DF2, c("NAME"="xy.NAME"))` before merging and using `by="xy.NAME"` in the `merge` call or using the `by` parameter for the `inner_join` i.e.  `ij <- inner_join(DF1, DF2, by = c("xy.NAME" = "NAME"))`.

Comment: `merge` is going to give you an "adventure" when DF1$NAME = c('a', 'a') and DF2$NAME = c('a', 'a').

Answer (score 23):

Use the `ifelse` function. Here, I put NA when the condition is not met. However, you may choose any value or values from any vector.
Recycling rules[1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) apply.

```
DF1$Activity_new <- ifelse(DF2$NAME == DF1$NAME, DF2$Activity, NA)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to not change the left-hand column when the condition is not met. So the `NA` should be `DF1$Activity`

Comment: He said it was to be "a new column".

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this one actually needs an example. What happens when you create a column with a set of NA values and then assign the required rows with the same logical vector on both sides:

```
DF1$Activity <- NA
DF1$Activity[DF2$NAME == DF1$NAME] <- DF2$Activity[DF2$NAME == DF1$NAME]
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a more canonical way to write this, ideally without repeating the condition.

Comment: The lack of reproducible example is damnable, but my understanding is that line 1 isn't necessary. Activity already exists in DF1, and DF1 and DF2 are the same size. This is more of a "case where" solution in SQL than a join. This should the canonical R answer.

Comment: @AdamO I thought (7 years ago)  that an assignment to a non-existent column with indexing might fail, but I guess I was wrong about that. I just convinced myself that you were correct.

Comment: @IRTFM most certainly a useful feature, although built-in redundancies such as assigning "NA" or 0 or "" are still good ideas. The point is... regarding this mystery application... I believe the OP had a *pre-existing* value for ACTIVITY in DF1, so the problem boils down to re-assigning some values but not others. Trivial R. In fact, `ifelse` as proposed in the top answer, while intuitive, is not optimized and can bog down R very badly.

Comment: We can agree to disagree about the stated underlying situation. I still read the request as implying that there was no Activity column in DF1.